# How does a "Server to Server" tracking method(for redirect purposes) work?

Tags: url, redirect, url-routing, server-to-server

My company has various ways to sending across information via the web-services. One is called "server to server" and from what I understand, that means it's invisible to the client/web-user. But I don't see how this fits in with redirecting .

I'm just confused about this and how it works, any tips/pointers/comments welcome. Thanks

Comment: I think this server to server aproach is not used with redirections, but just to share information between servers. For the user perspective he is connected to a particular server, which act as proxy. or not?  Not sure if I understood what exactly your question is.

Comment: @devundef - thanks a lot - Yeah I know my question needs more concrete info. I'm a bit vague on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, you use a CURL or the like to communicate Server-to-Server the second server returns a URL which the first Server now sends the user to.  This allows you to privately communicate data to the second server that the user can not alter.  Which will be used to pre-populate a page for them.